# Symfony3 Server-sent events and referer

Tags: symfony, server-sent-events, http-referer

Using server-sent events i'm facing some issues ...

Indeed, since server-sent events modify HTTP headers, i cant get the referer  when, for example i'm getting logged in.

Configuring the login path to the referer send me to the server-sent event's URL ..

Do you know any way to fix this ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: So do you want after login to be redirected to the client's set referer headers? I'm not sure what you really need?

Comment: Yes ! Well, after loging in, if i use the default configuration to referer, it actually redirects me to (for exemple) /path/to/server-sent-event/service.
And i guess it's due to the server's events that modify headers and so referer is changed.

Comment: I wonder if storing as a variable and then setting in a session variable would work for you? For example you could store in a variable called referer like this: `$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');`

Comment: Yes i've thought about it, but how to say then after logging in redirect to this one ! moreover, it involves that i need to create a controller listener that will be called on each new page to change it ?